# How do you wait till all requests ran to completion

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a Web API using ASP.NET Core. My task now is to wait for all request ran to completion when the application is closing. So I think I need somehow to block main thread till all tasks are done.

I crated class to contain all tasks that were created by controller:

```
public static class GlobalTasks
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<int, Task> TaskDic;

    static GlobalTasks()
    {
        TaskDic = new Dictionary<int, Task>();
    }

    public static void WaitAll()
    {
        if (TaskDic.Any())
        {
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var item in TaskDic)
            {
                taskList.Add(item.Value);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static void Remove(int taskId)
    {
        TaskDic.Remove(taskId);
    }

    public static void Add(Task t)
    {
        TaskDic.Add(t.Id, t);
    }
}
```

then I just use `IHostApplicationLifetime` in `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` to wait all tasks when application stopping.

```
lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => GlobalTasks.WaitAll());
```

But as far as I can see, this is not causing to wait my tasks when I am closing application

Any recommendations / advice?

This is how I add Tasks to Dictionary

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Post([FromBody] Update update)
    {
        if (!isStoping)
        {
            GlobalTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                await _updateService.EchoAsync(update);
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
                GlobalTasks.TaskDic.Remove(Task.CurrentId.Value);
            }));
            return Ok();
        }
        else
            return StatusCode(500);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the tasks aren't already completed?

Comment: I added Thread.Sleep in the running task to check if we are waiting the completion

Comment: That doesn't necessarily confirm that the tasks are not already completed. Can you post more code about how you are adding the tasks?

Comment: I edited post with Task craetion code

Answer (score 2):

The host will give you only [5 sec](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f007634b02c4484f60ead75a893eb7f89f615ccf/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostOptions.cs#L17) to finish all tasks before brutally aborting everithing. You have two options to increase it:

1. `UseShutdownTimeout()`

   ```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                });
   ```
2. Add [configuration key](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3e9ae8e5eee2930da0096ab4ca4976f5938df648/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/WebHostDefaults.cs#L80) to appsettings.config

   `"ShutdownTimeoutSeconds": 60`

But. You should use [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to perform your tasks instead of managing static dictionary and blocking threads. You can implement [Producer-Consumer pattern](https://medium.com/@jaiadityarathore/multi-threaded-producer-consumer-using-net-core-channels-d43bb220e2e7) where `Producer` is your controller and `Consumer` is `BackgroundService`. Asp.Net Core will wait until all `BackgroundService`s finish they work (but not longer than `ShutdownTimeoutSeconds`) and gracefully shutdown.