# How is token.IsCancellationRequested false when I hit CTRL C?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The TLDR: Hitting CTRL C works for the initial worker service code, but adding in any sort of complexity seems to break the functionality.

If I create a blank C# worker service project, I get the following code:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Playing around with this, if I run from the command line, and then hit CTRL C, I see the message:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Application is shutting down...
```

And all is well.  The app exits.  As I began working on this project, I added in a TCP client, and I was always careful to keep this basic framework intact.

However, in testing it seems like I could sometimes hit CTRL C, see the application shutting down message, but the app does not exit.  At first it seemed like reading IsCancellationRequested was causing the event to reset, so I changed to a class level variable that periodically reads that bool and used the bool everywhere else for the check.  I thought that fixed the problem, but it was probably just a lucky coincidence.  Now, I can firmly say the app does not exit when I hit CTRL C.  If I add in a breakpoint, I can see when the code reaches the check that IsCancellationRequested returns false, even though I hit CTRL C and saw the app exiting message before the breakpoint was hit.

Does this thing even work?  If no one has any answers, I will see if I can create a minimal example that exhibits the behavior.  I tested the fresh worker project code I posted and it definitely works as expected.  I don't see how my additions could cause any problems.

EDIT:

Here is an extremely minimal addition that will reproduce this bug (?).  Connecting to 127.0.0.1 will of course fail, but the cancellation info is gone by the time that exception is handled:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            try
            {                    
                using (var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8090))
                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("connected to socket");
                }                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Exception in ExecuteAsync {mess}, {trace}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

I can't get the log to stay in a code block in my post here, but it just shows application shutting down, and the loop never exits.

EDIT 2:

How is this not a bug?  Calling synchronous code causing the rest of the program to behave improperly? Per Stephen's suggestion, I made the following change and now it properly exits:

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);               
            try
            {                    
                using (var client = new TcpClient())                    
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 8090);
                    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("connected to socket");
                    }
                        
                }                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Exception in ExecuteAsync {mess}, {trace}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }               
        }            
    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

During development and testing, I tested against Netcat running on a Linux system.  When I did the final deploy today, the actual socket being connected to is a SICK controller.  The async code did not work.  I reverted it to the version I started with and it now works.  It will run as a service that never stops, so I guess I don't care that it doesn't exit properly.  But I am having some doubts about C# and async that I didn't have before.  Yay.

Comment: Most likely this is caused by some `BackgroundService` / `IHostedService` / `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` handler that is synchronously blocking the shutdown.

Comment: Do you mean you see `Worker running at:..` message after `Application is shutting down...`?

Comment: @Artur, correct, the loop never exits. The IsCancellationRequested never becomes true

Comment: @StephenCleary - but what service?  The minimal repeatable code I posted is an empty project with a single call to TCPClient.

Comment: I have just added `Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled: {stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested}");` line after the loop and it prints `Cancelled: true`. So this example doesn't really reproduces the issue. What I can think about is that the code inside your real loop takes more than 5 sec to check for cancellation. Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64959826/2557855

Comment: @Artur good catch.  The connect attempt + the exception handling takes more than 5 seconds.  What is at fault here is that I only have 5 seconds to test for cancellation or I miss it.  That is bonkers.  The application doesn't exit and the code continues to run.  That just means this is some stupid artifact of how broken windows is.  Unix would not have this problem.  Post your answer down below and I will mark it correct.  Actually, rereading your answer, I wonder if I am hitting a framework bug because my framework is out of date.  I am going to try updating everything.

Comment: Not sure I have correct answer. You say `or I miss it` but cancelled token stays cancelled forever, it can't be reset. Try to increase `ShutdownTimeoutSeconds` and debug you code again. If token wasn't cancelled, you probably don't use original token received in `ExecuteAsync` but something else.

Comment: Definitely something funky going on here.  I updated VS from 16.9.4 to 16.10.0 and I can still see the issue.  Trivial code additions change the behavior though.

Comment: As @StephenCleary said you probably have **another** `BackgroundService` or `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` handler executing **before** this worker that hangs shutdown and your worker's `StopAsync` method not called. Check [`BackgroundService.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L13) to learn how it works

Comment: @lopass: Your `TcpClient` connection code is synchronous. If you want to make it cancelable, you need to [call `ConnectAsync` and pass a `CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync?view=net-5.0) instead. In fact, *all* your TCP/IP I/O should be asynchronous.

Comment: @StephenCleary See edit 2 - if you put your comment in an answer, I can mark it correct.